# hql and inheritance

Tags: hibernate, hql

I have the following HQL statement:

```
    Query q = session.createQuery(
        "SELECT ze " +
        "FROM NormaleZone zo " +
        "LEFT JOIN zo.zaal za " +
        "LEFT JOIN za.vertoningen v " +
        "LEFT JOIN zo.normaleZetels ze " +
        "WHERE v = :vertoning " +
        " AND zo = :zone " +
        " AND ze NOT IN (SELECT t.zetel FROM Ticket t WHERE t.vertoning = :vertoning)"
    );
```

The problem I have is that `NormaleZone` inherits from `Zone`, as do `HandicapZone` and `LoveZone`.

What I would like to do is the following:

```
    Query q = session.createQuery(
        "SELECT ze " +
        "FROM Zone zo " +
        "LEFT JOIN zo.zaal za " +
        "LEFT JOIN za.vertoningen v " +
        "LEFT JOIN zo.??? ze " +
        "WHERE v = :vertoning " +
        " AND zo = :zone " +
        " AND ze NOT IN (SELECT t.zetel FROM Ticket t WHERE t.vertoning = :vertoning)"
    );
```

You can see I put `zo.???` in there. The object of this HQL is to find out which seats have not yet been taken in a movie theater. The problem is that the abstract class `Zone` has no seats (the `ze` would be the alias for seats).

I don't understand how I can solve this besides looking at the incoming `Zone` object in that method and then making two strings, one for the zone and one for the seats and then concatenating them in the HQL string.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

there is a hidden property which indicates the class of an object. Use `ze.class = :seatclass` and ("seatclass", Seat.class)